# Trying to figure out why my SSD doesnt show up in devices or drives and disk management

Tags: ssd

I have a samsung SSD 860 evo. I connected it to my mother board and power supply but it didn't show up in disk management or devices and drives. So i used a usb adapter and it showed up in disk management so i did that whole process and it worked. Then i connected it to the mother board and power supply again but it still didn't appear

Comment: If you include the model of your motherboard, we can give more specific advice. What's happening isn't the SSD's fault. It's something to do with the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

Three things to try:

- try a different SATA cable
- try a different SATA port on your motherboard
- ensure all SATA ports are enabled in the BIOS:

[image]

Comment: I have sataexpress12,  sata 6g e12,  sata 6g 12. Does it matter where?

Comment: It can matter, particularly as it's possible to disable SATA ports in the BIOS. I would try one port from each group until you find one that works. You might want to look in the BIOS first to make sure nothing's disabled.

Comment: I have the republic of gamers eufi bios. Cant seem to find an option for sata ports

Comment: Look under `Advanced` then `SATA Configuration`.

Comment: Found it. Says there all enabled tho

Comment: Systematically try every SATA port and make a note of which ones work. It'll take a few minutes but it'll be worth it!

Comment: Ok i tried it.  Didnt work. Swtiched the cables for my hard drive and ssd to see if it was just a bad cable but it still works